# Compile time error occur bit it did not affect anything xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am getting this error:

> Error Unable to remove directory "obj\Debug\81\android\bin\classes". The directory is not empty.  DipsDemoXaml.Android

But It does not affect my code for building. But it causes when I try to test my code with unit testing and try to run all test once. Run them selecting one by one is not a problem.

What's the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you delete this file manually? I.e. is a process using that file?

Comment: I cannot delete that file it effect my project

Comment: @ish1104 Do you have a try with clean project,or go to the root directory of the project and delete the obj and bin folders.